# Using Python os.execl* replace self process

Tags: python, process, web2py

I want to replace the self process (running web2py) with different parameter such as bind ip address using Python os.execl* function. Although it success to replace the instance that I found actually it did not KILL the original process but only create a new child process. For example, the original web2py process is running on 10.1.1.1:8000. Then in page's controller it runs,

`os.execl('python', 'python', 'web2py.py', '--ip=10.1.1.2', '--port=8000', '--password=')`

Ok now we can open the webpage on 10.1.1.2:8000. But if we change back to 10.1.1.1:8000 in the same process again. The new process complain the port has been used by another process.

Is there another way to "REFRESH" web2py service by himself?

Comment: Can't you simply release all resources (e.g. close sockets and files etc.) before the call to `exec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.execl` is replacing the current process, but it's retaining the open port; the error message that "the port is in use by another process" is incorrect, it's actually in use by the current process.

On Unix, open file descriptors are inherited across a call to `exec`, unless the fd is marked close-on-exec with `FD_CLOEXEC`.  This is noted as an issue at http://bugs.python.org/issue12107.

You should tell web2py to close the port before re-execing your process, or mark the fd as close-on-exec using [`fcntl`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/fcntl.html) module:

```
fcntl.fcntl(socket, fcntl.F_SETFD, fcntl.fcntl(socket, fcntl.F_GETFD) | fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
```